# Extract substring from filename and count

Tags: batch-file

Example below - 5 files will be located in the same folder.

```
Sales-fid1000-f100.dat
Revenue-fid1000-f100.dat
Sales-fid2000-f200.dat
Revenue-fid2000-f200.dat
Income-fid2000-f200.dat
```

I need to read the filename and get the number after "fid", in this case 1000 and 2000 and count the number of files associated with each "fid".

So for fid1000, there are 2 files and for fid2000, there are 3 files.

I need to write the output into a .txt file as below with first field being the fid number and second field being the count.

```
1000|2
2000|3
```

How can I generate output text file with fid and count using a Windows batch file?

Comment: try a `for` loop over the names with a `set` to extract the substring from the filename. If you have a more detailed question come back and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all file names
for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.dat') do (

   rem Get FID from second dash-delimited token; format: "xxx-fid####-xxx.dat"
   set "fid=%%a"

   rem Accumulate it to the corresponding element of "count" array
   set /A "count[!fid:~3!]+=1"
)

rem Create the output
(for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do echo %%a^|%%b) > output.txt
```

For further details on array management in Batch files, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Thank you very much Aacini. Worked perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-fid*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 CALL :process
)
(
 FOR  /F "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(%%a^|%%b
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "filename=%filename:*-fid=%"
FOR /f "delims=-" %%q IN ("%filename%") DO SET /a $%%q+=1
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

After clearing all the `$` variables (for safety's sake), perform a directory listing without directorynames and in basic form of files in the source directory matching *-fid*.

For each name found, assign the name to `filename` and execute the `:process` routine, which first removes the characters up to and including `-fid` from `filename` then uses the `delims=-` option to assign the part originally between `-fid` and the following `-` to `%%q`.

`set`the variable `$%%q` up by 1 (if $?? is undefined, assign `1`)

Finally, when all the names have been processed, list the variables named `$...` using `set` which produces a report of the style

```
$1000=2
$2000=3
```

Using `$` and `=` as delimiters puts token 1 (eg `2000`) into `%%a` and token 2 (eg `3`) into `%%b`. Write these to the output using `echo`, remembering to escape the pipe (`|`) with a caret (`^`) to suppress the interpretation as a redirector.

The parentheses around the `for...$...` ensures the output is directed to the destination file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the numbers into a temporary file, then count the occurrences of each number in that file.

```cmd
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

>temp.txt type nul
set "unique_num="

for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b *.dat') do (
  set "fid=%%a"
  set "num=!fid:~3!"
  >>temp.txt echo !num!
  echo " !unique_num! " | find " !num! " >nul
  if !errorlevel! neq 0 set "unique_num=!unique_num! !num!"
)

for %%n in (%unique_num%) do (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%c in ('find /c "%%n" temp.txt') do (
    set "count=%%c"
    echo %%n^|!count: =!
  )
)

del /f /q temp.txt
```

Pipe the result into `sort` if you need the output sorted.